# Webcam input sent through OpenCV to pyvirtualcam results in slow frame rate (Mac)

Tags: python, performance, opencv, camera, face-detection

Hello smart people of this planet.

I'm manipulating live video from my webcam (MacBook) to do some face detection using OpenCV and then I export it to a virtual webcam using pyvirtualcam(OBS). By doing this I can open the manipulated live video during meetings in Google meets, Zoom, etc..

So far I have managed to get everything working BUT it is suuuper slow, although I am setting the framerate to 20fps, it is more like 2fps.

Does anyone have an idea how I can optimize this to get a smooth video?

This is my code (It detects faces and puts a red rectangle around them):

```
import cv2
import pyvirtualcam
import face_recognition

captr = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fmt = pyvirtualcam.PixelFormat.BGR
face_locations = []
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=20, fmt=fmt) as cam:
    while True:
        ret_val, frame = captr.read()
        face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
        
        for top, right, bottom, left in face_locations:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720), interpolation=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

        # cv2.imshow('my webcam', frame)
        cam.send(frame)
        cam.sleep_until_next_frame()
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break  # esc to quit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: profile your code. why do you expect it to be fast when you have it perform face recognition? that's not a cheap operation. and why do you _sleep_ at all? it's not that easy. frames from the camera will queue up, causing huge latency on top of every other problem you have. you'll have to either apply some dirty tricks to the VideoCapture object, or spawn a thread to read as quickly as possible from the VideoCapture, and then use or discard the frames from that

Comment: I can't test your code because the `face_recognition` module is not available (at least without hacks) on Windows. However, the are some suggestions I can offer: 1) Consider resizing your input image. Do you really need a 1280 x 720 frame to detect/recognize faces? Maybe a smaller resolution will do. 2) This is more related to processing frame rate. Maybe decimating (lowering) the acquisition frames can help you boost your performance.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz `sleep_until_next_frame()` adapts dynamically to the target frame rate and therefore takes per-frame processing time into account. Frames are not queued up. I do agree though it's probably running way out of budget because of the face recognition.

Comment: that's the *target* rate. you need to consider the *source* rate as well. video cameras don't just take pictures when you ask them to, they do it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for posting your thoughts about this.

I remembered that I came across an [OpenCV face-detection tutorial](https://medium.com/geeky-bawa/face-detection-in-python-using-a-webcam-ba8e3f31eb47) a while ago, that was working without problems considering the Framerate.

So I used the code from the tutorial in combination with pyvirtualcam and the result is perfect for what I want.

I'm still pretty new with this and would like to know, why my code works fast now vs my old slow code.

Here is my new code:

```
import cv2
import pyvirtualcam
import numpy as np

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
video_capture.set(3,1280)
video_capture.set(4,720)
fmt = pyvirtualcam.PixelFormat.BGR
with pyvirtualcam.Camera(width=1280, height=720, fps=25, fmt=fmt) as cam:
    while True:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.2,
        minNeighbors=5,     
        minSize=(20, 20)
    )
        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
            roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1280, 720), interpolation=cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

        # cv2.imshow('my webcam', frame)
        cam.send(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break  # esc to quit
    video_capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I'm guessing it's because I'm shifting calculations with the usage of the haarcascade?
Or am I totally wrong here?